# How to fetch Enhanced ecommerce data from analytics using Google analytics Reporting API - PHP

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I configured google analytics and integrated Enhanced ecommerce report of my website. [(Screenshot - Analytics Dashboard)](https://ibb.co/bXDbTKQ)

Now I want to fetch the analytics reports via API. I could successfully fetch the reports in "Audience Overview". But I couldn't fetch the reports in "Ecommerce Shopping Behavior".

I used [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4 PHP](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) and [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) for fetching data.

I want to fetch "**Sessions with Add to Cart**" and "**Sessions with Transactions**" [(Screenshot)](https://ibb.co/jy2hq9T). But I don't know which metrics are using for these data.

Does any one know how can we fetch the data in "**Ecommerce Shopping Behavior**" with analytics reporting API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fetching 'Enhanced Ecommerce - Shopping Behavior' data, you can use "Shopping Stage" Dimension.

It will provide the informations in Various stages of the shopping experience like PRODUCT_VIEW, ADD_TO_CART, CHECKOUT etc.

So in your case, you want results based on sessions. So try Dimension as "***ga:shoppingStage***" and Metrics as "***ga:sessions***"